# How to create cucumber feature file from excel sheet or other file

Tags: excel, typescript, protractor, cucumber

I have an excel sheet where my scenarios are added . From the excel sheet , those scenarios need to converted to feature file . Can you please help me in this ? How this can be achieved by using any plugins .

Please help?

The scenarios will be created in excel sheet , from there the each row should be created as Feature step using gherkins keyword

Excel sheet : Attached as below for reference

[image: scenariosSheet]

Comment: I will advice to stop using excel and start store this inside the repository

Comment: Repository in the sense, to directly create as feature file. Our approach is to use the existing manual test case scenarios and steps which can be automated . Summary of the test case to be Scenario in cucumber and test steps as cucumber steps. Please suggest

Comment: Create a script which reads excel and creates the feature file. Run this in the beforeLaunch callback. Would be easy for the case u have mentioned but will be a pain for anything non-trivial. The ideal solution is the one already mentioned by Oleksii.

Comment: Is it one test per sheet and many sheets per rulebook? Also could you include what you expect the example you gave to look like as a `.js` or `.ts` file?

Comment: @DublinDev - its multiple test and multiple sheets based on pages across website . The file should be saved as .feature , since the expectation is to create a feature file from excel sheet

Comment: I'd love to have this. Of course plain text is easier to version control - yet it would be a pain letting QAs edit plain text (different spaces/tabs here and there when you add new columns; difference when you copy the file to/from team wiki - for example)

If the OP has the code to convert from Excel to feature file and willing to share to GitHub, it's great

Answer (score 2):

You could use the below package to read the contents of excel file into JSON object.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-excel-to-json

```
//read.js
const parser = require('simple-excel-to-json');
const doc = parser.parseXls2Json(`Sample.xlsx`);

doc[0].forEach((data, i) => {
    console.log(`${i} ${data.name} ${data.age}`)
})
```

where name and age are the column names.

[image]

[image]

You can append all the required values in a string with matching literals.

later you can write it to file.

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile("test_input.feature", /* string to be written */, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

You can write the file saving logic in read.js itself.

In your protractor config file mention the folder where you will save the feature files.